# How can I recover from 'Bus Error' in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: server

I am trying to deploy a NextJS app in my Ubuntu 20.04. But after installing the dependencies (around 16 of them), I tried to run the app but getting something called 'Bus error'.

[image]

I have tried reproducing the issue with an app which has around 4 dependencies and it deploys perfectly.

As I am still learning Linux and Ubuntu, I still couldn't find the actual issue. Can anyone here help me out in solving this issue? It would be a big help as I am just clueless here.

Here's what my RAM usage shows on my VPS:

[image]

Here's my VPS information:

> Distributor ID: Ubuntu
>
> Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
>
> Release:        20.04
>
> Codename:       focal

These are the programs which are taking up most ram:

```
[21:47] [server1.example.com test2] # ps -e -o pid,cmd,%mem --sort=-%mem
    PID CMD                         %MEM
    787 /usr/sbin/mysqld            17.3
   1294 /usr/bin/ofelia daemon --do  6.1
   4203 rspamd: controller process   4.4
   4204 rspamd: normal process (*:1  3.9
   2252 rspamd: main process         3.9
   4201 rspamd: fuzzy process (*:11  3.8
   4202 rspamd: rspamd_proxy proces  3.7
   2239 mysqld                       2.8
   2002 node /home/boomboom/node-apps  2.8
    962 node /home/boomboom/node-apps  2.2
    793 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// -  2.1
    940 node /home/boomboom/node-apps  1.6
    985 node /home/boomboom/node-apps  1.5
    934 npm start                    1.4
   2389 python3 -u /app/dockerapi.p  1.4
    950 node /home/boomboom/node-apps  1.2
    841 PM2 v5.1.1: God Daemon (/ho  1.2
    842 PM2 v5.1.1: God Daemon (/ro  1.2
    493 /usr/lib/snapd/snapd         1.1
   2163 python3 -u /server.py        1.1
   3612 /usr/sbin/sogod              1.1
    756 /usr/bin/containerd          1.0
   3526 /usr/sbin/sogod              1.0
   3595 /usr/sbin/sogod              0.9
   3598 /usr/sbin/sogod              0.9
   3596 /usr/sbin/sogod              0.9
   3597 /usr/sbin/sogod              0.9
```

Comment: Could it be the fact that the server is started on port 3001, but is expected to run on port 3000?

Comment: @Jos No. I changed the port. Still getting Bus Error. I also stop mysql server as it was using up most of the RAM. It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I had the same problem—at least, I hope I did. Here is the solution I was able to implement.

1. Reboot your computer.
2. Delete the folders "node module" and ".next"
3. Delete your package-lock.json file
4. Run `npm i` or `npm install`.
5. Run `npm run dev`.

I'm hoping this resolves the problem. If this still doesn't work for you, please leave a comment.